# Unable to load .so file in android with github bump demo

Tags: android, shared-libraries, bump

I hav downloaded bump demo from github but when i am running this its craching all the time with error log as

```
11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library
android-api not found 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at     
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at com.bump.api.BumpAPI.<init>   
(BumpAPI.java:122)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at      
 java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2940)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 11-16 12:33:01.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4298):     at 
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

while i am using this bloack of code for loading it in onCreate

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        //System.loadLibrary("mysharedlibrary");
        //crashing on this line
        System.loadLibrary("libgifflen.so");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError use) {
        Log.e("JNI", "WARNING: Could not load libmysharedlibrary.so");
        System.out.println("warning  "+use.getMessage());
    }
   //.......some other code
 }
```

I think i am missing something very string thing but i am unable to find any such thing or unable to get something for this

Comment: Are you tried `System.loadLibrary("libgifflen");`?

Comment: @camobap yes..i also mentioned this in in my code..here in try catch encapsulated by onCreate block

Comment: As I can see you have problem with `android-api` library `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library ***android-api*** not found`

Comment: yes i hav seen this but i am unable to find why this is coming..my other projects are running..i think i hav setted wrong project propeties..so i m retrying to set those..n let u know asap

Comment: i hav my lib structure as follows libs containing android-support-v4.jar,bumpapi.jar and a folder containing libgifflen.so

Comment: i am not having ndk plugin on one eclips..is it needed??..also having on another but still facing the same...may be the reason first time i am using ndk so path not configured correctly.but during this its not provided me any error.so i found it right..suggest me something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have imported the bump-library to my project and it works.

1. Import in your eclipse the bump-api-library project
2. Select the bump-api-library > Properties > Android >  Make sure the "Is Library" is selected > Click "Apply" then "OK"
3. Select your project > Properties > Android > Click the "Add" button > select the "bump-api-library" > Click "Apply" then "OK"

Comment: I have just put in a .zip the BumpTest and the bump-api-library projects.  I have tested it and it works on my end.  Just make sure you place your own API_KEY in the BumpTest MainActivity.java https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8f-N2PC8e0vU0gxRm1jaG51RGM